# Installing File::MMagic using CPAN but can't be found in @INC

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

I've tried installing File::MMagic in CPAN using

```
install File::MMagic
```

in CPAN.

When I try to call my script and associated variable (which uses File::MMagic) it fails telling me that File/MMagic.pm can't be found in @INC. Unsure how to proceed, all suggestions welcome! I'm on Mac OS Sierra

Comment: On Linux Ubuntu 16.04 command `sudo cpan install File::MMagic` works ok. So problem probably id connected with operating system.

Comment: yes it does. NO, DON'T. - install cpanm first (curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus), then install any module of your liking like the above with: cpanm File::MMagic

Comment: @vanHoesel, That's not gonna help at all. Please refrain from posting advertisements of your personal preferences.

Comment: Re "*I've tried installing File::MMagic in CPAN using*", "Tried"? What happened? Also, please provide the output of `set | grep ^PERL ; echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep 'make\|mbuild'`.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this. The answer could be found in the error message. When it installs File::MMagic the directory structure it creates doesn't include a File directory. The script is trying to call File/MMagic.pm. By creating a new directory and calling it File and putting MMagic.pm in there it ran successfully.

Comment: "When it installs File::MMagic the directory structure it creates doesn't include a File directory." it literally does `Installing /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/File/MMagic.pm`